# Editando um registro com Daialog framework do primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces, java-ee, jsf-2.2, servlet

Sou iniciante no mundo java e java web, começando com jsf, primefaces e estou com um problema que não estou conseguindo resolver.
Tenho um dataTable listando alguns dados, tenho o evento ajax para selecionar a um campo na tabela e um botão editar. ao fazer isso ele deveria abrir uma janela modal com os dados para fazer a edição, isso que não estou conseguindo fazer.

Código da janela modal:

```
public void abrirDialogo() {
    Map<String, Object> options = new HashMap<>();
    options.put("modal", true);
    options.put("resizable", false);
    options.put("width", 400);
    options.put("height", 300);

    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().openDialog("frmEstadosMan", options, null);
}
```

Código do evento ajax

```
<p:ajax event="rowSelect"/>
```

Código do botão editar

```
<p:commandButton title="Editar" value="Editar" icon="fa fa-edit"   
        action="#{estadosBean.abrirDialogoEdt}" process="@this"> 
<f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{estadosBean.estado}" value="#{estado}" />
</p:commandButton>
```

Em algumas vezes que editei o código, a janela de edição até abriu, mas vazia, sem os dados da linha do grid que foi selecionada.

Answer (score -1):

Se vc seguir o exemplo primefaces pode te ajudar...

https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/selection.xhtml

Onde no *commandButton* tem um *setPropertyActionListener* que seta o objeto *car* para a variavel *selectedCar* no seu beam, e o *oncomplete* abre sua caixa de dialogo *multiCarDialog* visualizando os dados da variável.

```
<p:dataTable id="basicDT" var="car" value="#{dtSelectionView.cars1}">
    <p:column headerText="Id">
        <h:outputText value="#{car.id}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Year">
        <h:outputText value="#{car.year}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column style="width:32px;text-align: center">
         <p:commandButton update=":form:carDetail" oncomplete="PF('carDialog').show()" icon="ui-icon-search" title="View">
            <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{car}" target="#{dtSelectionView.selectedCar}" />
        </p:commandButton>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Caixa de diálogo

```
<p:dialog header="Car Info" widgetVar="carDialog" modal="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" resizable="false">
    <p:outputPanel id="carDetail" style="text-align:center;">
        <p:panelGrid  columns="2" rendered="#{not empty dtSelectionView.selectedCar}" columnClasses="label,value">
            <f:facet name="header">
                <p:graphicImage name="demo/images/car/#{dtSelectionView.selectedCar.brand}-big.gif"/> 
            </f:facet>

            <h:outputText value="Id:" />
            <h:outputText value="#{dtSelectionView.selectedCar.id}" />

            <h:outputText value="Year" />
            <h:outputText value="#{dtSelectionView.selectedCar.year}" />

            <h:outputText value="Color:" />
            <h:outputText value="#{dtSelectionView.selectedCar.color}" style="color:#{dtSelectionView.selectedCar.color}"/>

            <h:outputText value="Price" />
            <h:outputText value="$#{dtSelectionView.selectedCar.price}" />
        </p:panelGrid>
    </p:outputPanel>
</p:dialog>
```

Claro que para edição, você vai precisar de colocar um form na caixa de dialogo com os componentes que desejar e um botão para salvar as informações...

Comment: Sim amigo, mas a forma que estou fazendo não é com p <p:dialog>, e sim com o framework do primefaces, método diferente de abrir janelas modais.